# Sql 2008 code to open file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

What is the SQL 2008 code to open a file, append some new lines, and save the file.  Is there a way to do this all inside a stored procedure?  Also, is there a way to automatically retrieve the script to do this from a "Tasks"->"Generate Scripts" menu options, or at least get close.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve (other than write to a file)? File handling would normally be something the business level code handles, so knowing the problem you're trying to solve would help us understand *why* you're wanting to do this from within SQL.

Comment: I know this can be done with the task->geneate script command set.  I can retrieve data from a file a put it into another file or a table.  I want to be able to retrieve the script from this generate script command, not just perform the operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with plain T-SQL...

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

**to make it work, click on those links in the text as well...**

http://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/uftReadFileAsTable.txt

http://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/spWriteStringTofile.txt

Or you might write a function in c#...

http://blog.adampresley.com/2009/writing-csharp-functions-for-sql-server-and-clr-integration/

Comment: I typed in: using master    Select line from uftReadfileAsTable('C:\Users\myname\Documents','test.html') where line not like '#%'                       --where line doesnt begin with a hash                             Unfortunately I  got this error message: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid object name 'uftReadfileAsTable'.   So it doesn't look like this works.

Comment: I don't think you can say "plain old T-SQL" in relation to SPs using Windows specific OS calls.